# I can't get value outside the onDataSnapshot in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I'm trying to do is get the value outside of `OnDataSnapshot` but it always returns `null`. How do I access it from outside?
It is always returning null because of being asynchronous.
I have tried almost all the methods of Stack Overflow but none worked for me.
Help me to get this value out of that function.
Below is my code: I have declared String Outside

```
final DatabaseReference grpinfo = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid).child("Group");
    //listner not working properly
    grpinfo.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            group = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            //cant get this value outside

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    //returns null in Toast
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),group,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Please include the text of your code in the post rather than an image of it.

Comment: have your tried to take `static`

Comment: void getDataSnapShot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)  create function and use it outside

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are in an activity, why do you don't create a setter inside your activity with a string param to save your data?

```
private String group;
public void setGroup(String group){
   this.group = group;
}
```

And in your onDataChange method you set your group :

```
String group = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
setGroup(group);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are a declaring a new `group` String every time the listener triggers, therefore trying to access `group`'s value outside of the listener's scope would retrieve null as it is not defined there.

To get a value from Firebase with listeners simply:

- Declare `String group` variable outside of the listener's scope
- in `onDataChange` simply assign `dataSnapshot`'s value to your string, this way `group` variable will be available (with its' new value) outside of the listener's scope.

E.g.

```
String group;

grppinfo.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(Datasnapshot datasnapshot) {
    group = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
    }
    ...
});
```

Note: It's good practice when retrieving data from Database to check if `datasnapshot` is not null, otherwise there might be cases when you will end up with a `nullPointerException` thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** simply declare `group` variable as a global variable and use it everyhere in your code because the `onDataChange()` method is called asynchronous. This means that the `Toast` that you are trying to display is called before even you are trying to get the data from the database and that's why is always `null`.

So in order to solve this, you need to use this line of code:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),group,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

inside `onDataChange()` method and it will work for sure or if you want to use that value outside `onDataChange()` method, i suggest you see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Answer (score 0):

I came across a dirty hack but it worked. I'm using SharedPreferences to store the value inside onDataChange then I used the SharedPreferences to get the value. It works fine since onDataChange is called everytime data is changed in the database hence updating sharedpreferences value. Here is the code.

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name= dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

            setKeys= getSharedPreferences("Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editKeys=setKeys.edit();
            editKeys.putString( "name",name);
            editKeys.apply();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```